# Pass drop down value from <apex:selectList> Visualforce page to the javascript in salesforce?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am developing a **code Easy Visualforce Charts with JavaScript Remoting & Google Charts API**. In this example I want to provide two options `ColumnChart` and `LineChart`. By default `ColumnChart` value should be selected. If I select any value then that value I want to pass it into my `onload` javascript function right here:

*var visualization = new google.visualization.**LineChart**(document.getElementById('chartBlock'));*

OR

*var visualization = new google.visualization.**ColumnChart**(document.getElementById('chartBlock'));*

How we can show that ?

**VFPage**

```
<apex:page controller="GoogleChartsController" sidebar="false">
     <!-- Google API inclusion -->
    <apex:includeScript id="a" value="https://www.google.com/jsapi" />
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Google Charts + Javascript Remoting" subtitle="Demoing - Opportunities by Exepected Revenue" />

    <apex:form >
      <apex:selectList size="1">
          <apex:selectOptions value="{!dynamiclist}"></apex:selectOptions>
      </apex:selectList>
    </apex:form>  


    <div id="chartBlock">
        <script>
            // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
            google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

            // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
            google.setOnLoadCallback(initCharts);

            function initCharts(){
                GoogleChartsController.loadOpps(
                    function(result, event){
                        // load Column chart
                        var visualization = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chartBlock'));
                         // Prepare table model for chart with columns
                         var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                         data.addColumn('string', 'Opportunity');
                         data.addColumn('number', 'Expected Revenue');
                         data.addColumn('number', 'Amount'); 

                         // add rows from the remoting results
                         for(var i =0; i<result.length;i++){
                            var r = result[i];
                            data.addRow([r.Name, r.ExpectedRevenue, r.Amount]); 
                          }
                        // all done, lets draw the chart with some options to make it look nice.
                        visualization.draw(data, {legend : {position: 'top', textStyle: {color: 'blue', fontSize: 10}}, width:window.innerWidth,vAxis:{textStyle:{fontSize: 10}},hAxis:{textStyle:{fontSize: 10},showTextEvery:1,slantedText:false}});
                }, {escape:true});
            }
        </script>
    </div>

</apex:page>
```

**GoogleChartsController**

```
global with sharing class GoogleChartsController{   
    @RemoteAction
    global static Opportunity[] loadOpps() {
        return [SELECT Id, Name, ExpectedRevenue, Amount FROM Opportunity ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 20];
    }

    global GoogleChartsController(){}

    global List<SelectOption> getdynamiclist() {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        options.add(new SelectOption('ColumnChart','ColumnChart'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('LineChart','LineChart'));
        return options;
    }
}
```

**Here is the dropdown and response:**

[image]

**and If select other option, then I should see like below**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the selected value of `selectList` in `JavaScript` you need to change your approach.

```
<apex:selectList size="1" styleclass="chartBlock">
      <apex:selectOptions value="{!dynamiclist}"></apex:selectOptions>
 </apex:selectList>
```

Now in your `JavaScript` get the value using `className` attribute and use that.

```
var e = document.getElementsByClassName("chartBlock")[0];
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

you need to change javascript here

```
var visualization = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chartBlock'));
```

to

```
var e = document.getElementsByClassName("chartBlock")[0];
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
 var visualization = new google.visualization.LineChart(strUser);
```

Comment: @user4567570 answer updated.

Comment: Thanks, but I dont see its properly working yet, debugging it, Nothing is rendering on the screen. Also when we changed the drop down value nothing is happening. Please look at it

Comment: We need to use strUser value in var visualization = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chartBlock')); I have also highlighted in my post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use action support to catch the value change.

```
<apex:selectList value="{!selectedValue}" size="1">
          <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="chartPanel"/>
          <apex:selectOptions value="{!dynamiclist}">
          </apex:selectOptions>

      </apex:selectList>
```

Then dirctly use in the vf script tag

when {!selectedValue} = "ColumnChart"  then load all column chart google script